# Related to user data in web development

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, database

Anyone tell me that where the *user data* (like photos, videos, posts) is saved?
Because I don't think that they goes in SQL or any similar database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you will use a service like [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for media (photos, videos, files, etc.). Blog posts (just text) will be in the database in a [text type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/string-data-types/). Media is usually renamed to a unique value and then referenced in the database.

However if this is a personal project not meant for public use you could store media locally in the filesystem ([NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php))